# How to add multiple dataframe to individual cells inside a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes that I have scraped from a website using `pandas.read_html()`. The tables that I get are not in proportion, meaning that they have different numbers of rows and columns, but they belong to a single entity. So I want to add all those dataframes to individual cells of the same row.
Here is an example.
I have the following dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]]*2)
df1

df2=pd.DataFrame([['a','b']]*3)
df2

df3=pd.DataFrame([[23,565,34,67,34]]*1)
df3

df4=pd.DataFrame([['df','grgrd','weddv','dfdf','re',45,93]]*5)
df4
```

and this how I am trying to do it:

```
dic={}
d['a']=df1
d['b']=df2
d['c']=df3
d['d']=df4
df_out=pd.DataFrame([d])
```

but the result looks like this:

```
a   b   c   d
0   0 1 2 0 1 2 3 1 1 2 3   0 1 0 a b 1 a b 2 a b   0 1 2 3 4 0 23 565 34 67 34 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 df g...
```

Looks like the index counters are also added as values to the cells.
How do I remove indices values?

Is there a way that they are stored in a way that they would appear as a table within individual cells?

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: try `d['a']=[df1]` etc and `df_out=pd.DataFrame(d)`

Comment: trying your way still includes indices in the values; however, I got the idea from your code and tried this d['a']=data[1].values.tolist() etc, and df_out=pd.DataFrame([d]), and the solutions comes clean

Comment: You should use a dictionary, list or something else. This is a horrible way to use pandas. Maybe you can try multiindex if you want to use pandas